# Corona Discharge, Leyden Jar and Free Charge

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, capacitance

Watching Walter Lewin's 8.02x- Lect 14, at the end of it, he explains the mechanism behind a Leyden jar. The (simplified) picture is the following:

[image: Walter Lewin's scheme of Leyden jar]
*Source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=By2ogrSwgVo*

Where the pink numbers represent electric field (V/m) and the green numbers potential difference. The vertical distances between the drawn plates are 1 mm, 3 mm, and 1 mm from top to bottom. The middle two plates represent a dielectric (glass) with dielectric constant $\kappa = 5$.

He then assures that with this data, we can obtain that the free charge on the glass (due to corona discharge from the upper and lower plates). He says it is 12 times larger than the free charge on the upper plate (made of an ordinary conductor). However, I do not know how to get his result.

**My Attempt**

I call $Q_p$ the free charge on the upper plate and $Q_g$ the free charge on the glass (second plate). If we consider the capacitor created by the top and bottom plates, its capacity is

$$ C = \epsilon_0 \kappa A/d $$

where $d = 5$ mm. Using that $Q = CV$, where $V$ is the potential difference between upper and lower plates, 30 kV, we get

$$ Q_p = \epsilon_0 \kappa A V/d \implies \sigma_p = \epsilon_0 \kappa V/d $$

Now the electric field between the glass plates is

$$ E_g = \sigma_g / \epsilon_0 \kappa \implies \sigma_g = \epsilon_0 \kappa E_g$$

Therefore,

$$ \sigma_g / \sigma_p = E_g d / V = 4/3 $$

As you can see, I do not get 12 but 4/3, and I ignore what is wrong with my solution. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Charge on top air capacitor $q=(\epsilon \, A/1)3$ and on the glass capacitor $Q=(5\epsilon \, A/3)24$.

Hence $Q/q=40/3$ and as net charge on glass is $Q-q$ the ratio of surface charge densities is $Q/q-1=37/3\approx 12$